# Complex numbers as algebraic integers

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

I am studying an undergraduate Number Theory course at university, and the following lemma appears:

*Let $V = \left\{\beta_1, ... \beta_n\right\}$ be a finite set of non-zero complex numbers.*

*Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ has the property that for each $i = 1,...,n$ the product $\alpha\beta_i$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of the elements in V.*

*Then $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.*

Initially I questioned whether this means that any complex number is an algebraic integer, on the basis that for any complex number $\alpha$ I could define the appropriate $V$ to make the above statement hold. I then realized that if I choose a complex number which has irrational real part and/or irrational imaginary coefficient, that won't work.

I maintain, however, that if I pick any complex number with real part in the quotients and coefficient to the imaginary part also in the quotients, then it is an algebraic integer. Is this true? If not, why not?

Comment: Have you looked at specific $\alpha$? e.g., $\alpha = \pi i$, $\alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt{-5}$, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. In the question, where I note that I realize there are complex numbers with irrational real part which are counter-examples, those sorts of things are what I meant. Perhaps I should emphasize that in the question I specifically ask about complex numbers not of the type which you are making examples of.

Comment: What I'm asking is: have you chosen specific $\alpha$ and then tried to determine what the corresponding $V$ is? e.g.,, if $\alpha = \sqrt{7}$, what does $V$ consist of?